# Java mpg calculator total

Tags: java

I have finished alot of the code. But now in the end i cant figure out how to get the totalMPG added from all the loops. Im really at a loss here with me limited experience with java.

```
     //initialization phase
     double stop = 1;
     double miles = 0;
     double gallons = 0;
     double avgMPG = 0;
     double totalMPG = 0;
     double trip = 0;

    // if the user enters zero it will stop the loop
    while (stop != 0)
    {  
        System.out.print("Enter a number for miles traveled, or enter 0 to exit: ");
        miles = input.nextInt();

        if (miles == 0)
        {
            //took me a while to figure out where th break goes and {} placement
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of gallons used: ");
            gallons = input.nextInt();
            avgMPG = miles/gallons;
            trip++;
            // i have tried multiple different ways to get totalMPG wont work
            totalMPG = mpg++ / trip++;
        }                              
    System.out.println("Your average MPG is " + avgMPG);
   }
    System.out.println("Your total trip MPG is " + totalMPG);

}
```

}

Comment: Use `+=`? Also, post increment doesn't give incremented value until next reference

Comment: where would i put += at?

Comment: In place of `=`

Comment: JavaScript and Java are NOT related.

Comment: Changed it to .... both??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only need to store your totalMiles and totalGallons, try this:

```
    //initialization phase
    double stop = 1;
    double totalMiles = 0;
    double totalGallons = 0;

   // if the user enters zero it will stop the loop
   while (stop != 0)
   {  
       System.out.print("Enter a number for miles traveled, or enter 0 to exit: ");
       double newMiles = input.nextInt();

       if (newMiles == 0)
       {
           //took me a while to figure out where th break goes and {} placement
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.print("Enter number of gallons used: ");
           double newGallons = input.nextInt();

           // i have tried multiple different ways to get totalMPG wont work
           totalMiles += newMiles;
           totalGallons += newGallons;

           System.out.println("Your average MPG is " + (newMiles/newGallons));
       }
  }

   System.out.println("Your total trip MPG is " + (totalMiles/totalGallons));
}
```